# Why does String.valueOf(Object obj) == null return false when argument obj is null?

Tags: java, null, boolean, equals-operator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Long lo = null;
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(lo) == null);
}
```

Why the above statement return false ?
Can anyone please explain..

Comment: We use "equals()" method to check equality for objects (String in this case), not "==".

Comment: @aakash you don't use `equals()` to check for null. It would never return false.

Comment: @shmosel I never said that you use `equals()` to check for `null`. Please read my comment again. Certainly there were some gaps in my comment, which I thought could be easily filled by OP's understanding of Java. `String.valueOf(lo)` would return a string "null", which is not null. So, if OP wants to check that, he should have used `String.valueOf(lo).equals("null")`. And as this is already answered by you, congrats.

Comment: @Aakash I think OP thought `String.valueOf(null)` returns `null`. In other words, he wasn't attempting to compare strings altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)):

> **Returns:**
>
> if the argument is `null`, then a string equal to `"null"`; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.

In other words, the result is the *string* `"null"`, not the *value* `null`.